# How much extra disk space does txindex=1 require?

Tags: storage-footprint, reindex

For example for a 1 MB block, does the extra Tx index database take up another 100 kB on average?

And a follow-up: once my node has completed `-reindex` after setting `txindex=1` can I COPY the blockchain AND the TX index database together to other nodes? I know the blockchain can be copied but I'm not sure if the new node needs to reindex the blockchain itself or if the index database copies over as well.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer becomes out-of-date very quickly to be useful to others in the future.

Comment: @MCCCS do you know of any block explorer, etc that publishes charts for blockchain size in MB?

Comment: https://www.blockchain.com/en/charts/blocks-size but not txindex

Comment: Maybe a new best answer could describe the ratio of the index directory to the blockchain size as described by that chart. This will be a common enough question to maintain some kind of answer here. For example the `indexes/txindex` directory seems to be about 10% the size of the `blocks` directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The total extra size is around 27GB as of June 2020. You can check by looking at the size of the `$DATADIR/blocks/index` directory.

If you copy that directory, you'll copy the index with it.

---

Historic data:

| Date | GB | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-11-18 | 7 | original answer |
| 2017-05-08 | 11 | [ens](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/43135/ens) |
| 2019-07-16 | 21 | [Vasil Toshkov](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/97001/vasil-toshkov) |
| 2020-06-14 | 27 | [Anonymous](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/24925/anonymous) |

Answer (score 1):

I just reindexed after setting txindex=1. My data directory increased in size about 3GB, but it seems like it might be saving data in another location since moving the data directory to other nodes is asking me to reindex.

Answer (score 0):

Given the table above from Pieter's accepted answer and considering the historic blockchain size at the same dates, index data is around 10% the size of the blockchain.