# What is the current size of txindex folder when txindex=1 set?

Tags: full-node, pruning, storage, txindex

Due to reputation limitations, I cannot ask for an update on this question:

[How much extra disk space does txindex=1 require?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48481/how-much-extra-disk-space-does-txindex-1-require/)

What is the current size of the txindex folder when txindex=1 is set in the bitcoin.conf file on a fully synced full node?
As pointed out in the referenced post, the size should now be around 28GB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> 27GB as of 2020-06-14
> ```

You yourself can check this via going to `.bitcoin/blocks/index` folder. Where .bitcoin folder is usually hidden folder on home when using linux.

It depends if you have pruned than the index folder might appear less in size. As of today my index folder is `105.4 MB` since I've `prune=1000` and it would remain the same in future as well.

Our question is answered [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48481/how-much-extra-disk-space-does-txindex-1-require) as well. Please check comment by [@anonymous](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/24925/anonymous)

Comment: `-txindex` and `-prune` are exclusive, only one of the two may be active at the same time. `-txindex` is inactive by default, and your folder size is smaller because you don't have a complete transaction index.

Comment: @Murch so if I have pruned=1000 doesn't it effect the size of transaction index? I think it will reduce the size.

Comment: What I meant was that `txindex` builds a complete transaction index which is 27 GB. This is incompatible with running a pruned node. Your node is running in pruned mode, so it cannot be running with a txindex at the same time. I'm not sure whether the index folder of a pruned node would be smaller than that of an archival node that doesn't build a transaction index.

Comment: @Murch yes it is smaller I have tested